# Postgres function using DDL statement

Tags: postgresql-9.4

I am trying to create function in Postgres which can automate user creation process but it doesn;t accept parameter in DDL statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AUTOUSER (uname varchar(20))
RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE 
      nm varchar(20);
BEGIN
    nm=$1;
    CREATE USER nm WITH PASSWORD 'Iash12';
    GRANT ALL ON DATABASE iashdb TO nm;
    GRANT ALL ON  ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO nm;
    RETURN CONCAT(nm,' Created');
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Above function create user as 'nm' instead of passed parameter name however RETURN statement showing correct result. Thanks in advance,

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for this: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: Dynamic SQL doesn't support DDL statement, it only support, SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE.

Comment: Of course it supports DDL. Where in the manual did you find that statement?

Comment: EXECUTE 'CREATE USER $1 WITH PASSWORD 'Iash12' '; shows me syntax error: syntax error at or near "' '"; tried with couple of different syntax but no luck so far.

Comment: You cant use it like this because:
"Another restriction on parameter symbols is that they only work in SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE commands. In other statement types (generically called utility statements), you must insert values textually even if they are just data values."

Answer (score 4):

You need to use dynamic SQL and you need to quote the parameters properly. The easiest way is to use the `format()` function with the appropriate placeholders:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AUTOUSER (uname varchar(20))
RETURNS TEXT AS $$
BEGIN
    execute format('CREATE USER %I WITH PASSWORD %L', uname, 'Iash12');
    execute format('GRANT ALL ON DATABASE iashdb TO %I', uname);
    execute format('GRANT ALL ON  ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO %I', uname);
    RETURN CONCAT(uname,' Created');
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The placeholder `%I` properly quotes SQL identifiers. The placeholder `%L` properly deals with string literals.